# Can I modify the Cinelerra interface?

Tags: interface, cinelerra

I don't like the Cinelerra interface. I tried to modify it but I didn't find a solution.

It is possible to put all the windows in Cinelerra on one window like in GIMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible unfortunately, but most of the time you work only with the main timeline window, you can reopen the other windows from the Window menu.